# Probability of two people having the same 7 digits in their phone number

Tags: probability

A friend was surprised that him and his sister had the exact same numbers in their phone number (minus the area code).

eg. my friend's number is 457 3375, and his sister's number is 374 5375. Same 7 numbers, in a different order.

What's the probability of this occurring?

Comment: Can you show some your ideas about this problem?

Comment: Presumably, you are allowed any $7$ digits, not starting with $0$? Used to be the case that the second digit couldn't be a $1$ or $2$, because that was the signal to the phone boards that it was the start of an area code.

Comment: @Thomas I was also under the impression that the first three numbers can't be 555.

Comment: Yes, although the numbers are used.  555-1212 was the weather line in Chicago. The reason they are used in movies is that they are supposed to be for automated general lines. @MattSamuel (Where I live now, it is information.)

Comment: @Thomas I seem to recall information in the area I was in when I was a kid having a similar number, but I think 411 could also have been used.

Comment: Yeah, 411 was the info number all over back then. "Give me the 411" was actual slang for requesting information from people. @MattSamuel

Comment: @Thomas yes, 411 was still used even when I was in college, which I graduated from 7 years ago. I'm saying there's another, longer number for information in my dimmer childhood memory that sounded a lot like 555-1212.

Answer (score 1):

An exact answer for # of possibilities for a 7 digit *string* $(0000000 - 9999999)$ would be:

*7 of a kind:* $\dbinom{10}1$

*6 - 1 of a kind:* $\dbinom{10}1\dbinom91\cdot\dfrac{7!}{6!}$

*5 - 2 of a kind:* $\dbinom{10}1\dbinom91\cdot\dfrac{7!}{5!2!}$

*5 - 1 - 1 of a kind:* $\dbinom{10}1\dbinom92\cdot\dfrac{7!}{5!}$

..........

*2 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 of a kind:* $\dbinom{10}1\dbinom95\cdot\dfrac{7!}{2!}$

*1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 of a kind:* $\dbinom{10}7\cdot7!$

Add up all and divide by $10^7$

Of course, you will have to make adjustments for excluding whatever configurations are invalid in your region for a telephone #

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Just take the probability of having the exact same number: $\frac{1}{10^7}$ and multiply that by the number of ways to rearrange the digits: 7! That's $$\frac{7!}{10^7} = \frac{101}{250,000}$$

Comment: Except that there are fewer permutations of some numbers, like $444-6666$.

Comment: For example, the given phone numbers are both permutations of $3345577$ and there are only $7!/8$ different permutations of those digits.

Comment: hmm. That's true. Disregard my answer.